# Where did using Pythagorean Theorem to find the absolute value of a complex number come from?

Tags: complex-numbers, proof-writing

Where did the idea of the Y axis being the complex axis come from? Is this arbitrary, or substantiated? I am thinking about back when I learned about the complex plane. For example $|3+4i|$ is known to be 5. Why the Pythagorean Theorem? Is there any mathematical proof that $|3+4i| = 5$? Where did using the Y axis to represent the complex axis, where did that come from?

Comment: That's immediate from the definition of the modulus of a complex number.

Comment: But where did that come from in the definition? How would finding the square root of a negative number+a real number involve that? @saulspatz

Comment: One can define the complex numbers as ordered pairs of real numbers, with component-wise addition, and a more complicated multiplication. Representing ordered pairs of reals in the Cartesian plane is, of course, familiar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a + bi$ is a complex number, then the complex conjugate $a-bi$ satisfies the same algebraic properties relative to $\mathbb R$ as $a+bi$. It turns out that if you multiply a complex number with its conjugate, you get a real number:
$$(a+bi)(a-bi) = a^2 -abi + abi - b^2i^2 = a^2+b^2,$$
which matches the Pythagorean identity that is mystifying you. Defining $$|a+bi| = \sqrt{(a+bi)(a-bi)}$$
is then convenient for many reasons, including the corollary that $|a+bi||c+di| = |(a+bi)(c+di)|$.

In particular, if $|a+bi| = 1$, then multiplication by $a+bi$ preserves distance (because $|(a+bi)(c+di)| = |c+di|$, and you can subtract two complex numbers to get the distance between them). This gives you a hint toward the fact that multiplying complex numbers with absolute value $1$ corresponds to rotation.

I believe that historically, the geometric connection between complex numbers and rotation was a huge step toward the acceptance of complex numbers as a meaningful notion of "number". Ethan Bolker or someone else would have to confirm or disconfirm that for me.

Answer (score 4):

Using a "fictitious" square root of $-1$  essentially started

> in the 16th century when algebraic solutions for the roots of cubic
> and quartic polynomials were discovered by Italian mathematicians (see
> Niccolò Fontana Tartaglia, Gerolamo Cardano).

Later in that [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number#History) entry:

> The idea of a complex number as a point in the complex plane (above)
> was first described by Caspar Wessel in 1799, although it had been
> anticipated as early as 1685 in Wallis's De Algebra tractatus.

Comment: Not where it was anticipated, but why?

Comment: Your question asks "where", not "why". The answer to "why" is in the history of "where". You could start by reading about Wessel.